# Are Chinese websites unfriendly to Google optimization? Why does my website always fail to rank on Google?

Tags: seo, local-seo, negative-seo

Are Chinese websites unfriendly to Google optimization? Why does my website always fail to rank on Google?
[image]

And why many people on this platform want to hack our China, we are also a free and safe country!

Comment: This question is opinion based and off topic. mine is China does not like Google and vice versa (Without judging thr merits of the action, China at ine stage banned Google, and that would have cost Google a lot - of Market shares and dollars). You likely arnt aware of it, but the overwhelming majority of attacks on "the wests" networks come from ex Soviet countries and China.  Like most of us are not bad, most Chinese are not, but governments and black hats dont play fair.  That said, CHINA is not free - you just dont hear about how oppressed and lied-to you are.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question.   There is a real answer.  You can't rank websites on `.com.cn` domains outside of China.  If you want to rank worldwide, you need to use a generic top level domain.  It doesn't make much sense to have a website in English on a Chinese country code domain if you want SEO.  It isn't just China, Google treats all country code domains like this except for a few which aren't used by the country and have been opened up for global registration.